# Get content of all <a> tags with class in php

Tags: regex, match

I got this code:

```
..some code here..
<a href="members/username1.12345/" class="username bigs" title="">Username 1</a>
..some code here..
..some code here..
<a href="members/username2.55334/" class="username bigs" title="">Username 2</a>
..some code here..
..some code here..
<a href="members/username3.23455/" class="username bigs" title="">Username 3</a>
..some code here..
..some code here..
<a href="members/username4.45545/" class="username bigs" title="">Username 4</a>
..some code here..
```

How to get the Username 1, Username 2, Username 3, Username 4, etc.. with preg_match_all() ??

I don't want to use SimpleHTMLdom or other.. I want to do it with preg_match_all().. how to do that ? I tried many regex's... but none of them worked..

Comment: *"I don't want to use SimpleHTMLdom or other."* Why not?

Comment: You DO NOT want to use regex for this. Period.

Comment: @antony my teacher ordered to do it with regex. So i havnt another option. Please someone do my homework and send me the solution

Comment: @silentboy: In this case he should tell his teacher that using regexes for this is stupid and point him to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @ThiefMaster: you're overestimating an average teacher's programming abilities

Comment: @theifmaster maybe the teacher know that  regex mustnt use to parse html. But the issue is for learning. Who need a `helloworld` program in his cariear

Answer (score 1):

Regexp is a horrible idea. But still - try this: `@<a href="members/.+/" class="username bigs" title="">(.+)</a>@U`

```
$subject = '..some code here..
<a href=\"members/username1.12345/\" class=\"username bigs\" title=\"\">Username 1</a>
..some code here..
..some code here..
<a href=\"members/username2.55334/\" class=\"username bigs\" title=\"\">Username 2</a>
..some code here..
..some code here..
<a href=\"members/username3.23455/\" class=\"username bigs\" title=\"\">Username 3</a>
..some code here..
..some code here..
<a href=\"members/username4.45545/\" class=\"username bigs\" title=\"\">Username 4</a>
..some code here..';

$pattern = '@<a href="members/.+/" class="username bigs" title="">(.+)</a>@U';

$result = preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $subpattern);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($subpattern, TRUE).'</pre>';
```

Comment: "Please someone do my homework and send me the solution" - Jesus. I feel like deleting my answer again. -.-

Comment: it wasn't OP, looks like it was just an irony

Comment: Whoops. Should read more carefully. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: the regex seems well. But the class could be more genarel. But +1 for  the hard works. Thanks